FFMPEG Raw bitstream from MKV/VOB error
Trying to convert a vob or mkv or mp4 video file into Raw bitstream using ffmpeg via ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb raw.h264 but keep getting the same error & I know nothing of ffmpeg other than google search. Any ideas, Thank you in advance!
Error Message
ffmpeg version 2024-06-21-git-d45e20c37b-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libquirc --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-libqrencode --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      59. 24.103 / 59. 24.103
  libavcodec     61.  8.100 / 61.  8.100
  libavformat    61.  3.104 / 61.  3.104
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
Input #0, mpeg, from '4.vob':
  Duration: 00:47:01.86, start: 0.060000, bitrate: 7777 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bottom first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 7000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
  Stream #0:3[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.0(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
[h264_mp4toannexb @ 0000020539e51540] Codec 'mpeg2video' (2) is not supported by the bitstream filter 'h264_mp4toannexb'. Supported codecs are: h264 (27)
[vost#0:0/copy @ 0000020539e77c00] Error initializing bitstream filter: h264_mp4toannexb
Error opening output file raw.h264.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument


The video codec of the input isn't h264 so you can't apply -c:v copy. Replace with -c:v libx264 and remove -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v libx264 raw.h264

You can use your original command if the input video stream says,
Stream #0: ... : Video: h264

